# How can I get back to the initial load screen of Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I've installed Raspbian onto my RPi's SD card from the [Raspberry Pi downloads](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

The first time I booted up the RPi, connected to a monitor, I got a list of options, with something like a `<select>` and `<return>` link at the bottom.

I'm trying to get back to this page in case there will config options here for setting up network settings.

However now when I load the RPi, it just goes to a command line screen with `$`.

How can I get back to that initial screen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get initial config menu by running `sudo raspi-config`.  Many settings changes will require a reboot.

Comment: as in the command `$ raspi-config`?

Comment: Try `sudo raspi-config` in a terminal or via ssh.

Comment: You can also find more information on what raspi-config and all the different options do here : http://elinux.org/RPi_raspi-config